# ¿Leer contenido de un archivo binario, que contiene enteros?

Tags: c, array

como se puede leer el contenido de un fichero ".bin" en el cual le hemos insertado números enteros.

Me gustaría saber como se pueden leer ese fichero, yo he usado la herramienta "fread" pero no me muestra nada o números aleatorios.

El fichero ".bin" contiene lo siguiente con el comando hexdump:

```
0000000 0020 0000 000b 0000 0061 0000 0012 0000
0000010 0017 0000 000a 0000                    
0000018
```

Es decir són números integers que he metido anteriormente mediante un array.

El objetivo es poder leer esos número, es decir, ese fichero.

Este es el código de mi programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
unsigned short lenght;
int i;
char * token;
int array[6];
float size;
FILE *file;


file= fopen("numeros.bin", "rb");

if (file==NULL)
{
printf("Error file not found\n");
return 1;
}

printf("-----------------------------\n");

printf("Quin nombre vols mostrar del fitxer binari:\n");
scanf("%u", &lenght );

fseek(file, lenght, SEEK_SET);
token=(char *)malloc(lenght+1);

fread( token, sizeof(lenght), 1, file);

printf("%x\n", token);


printf("-----------------------------\n");

fclose(file);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: > "en el cual le hemos insertado números enteros" En que formato? Debes especificarlo. Cada entero ocupa... 2 bytes? 4 bytes? Son signados o sin signo? Dicho de otra manera: viendo el contenido con el hexdump, cuáles (y cuantos) dirías que son los enteros archivados?

Comment: Perdón por no especificar, hay 6 enteros archivados.

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que sabes (lo sabes?) que cada entero ocupa 4 bytes (32 bits)... y suponiendo que no hay problemas de big-endianess vs little-endianess, entonces simplemente es cuestión de leer -y fseekear- de a 4 bytes. Por ejemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int pos, res, val;
        int width;
        width = sizeof(int); /* cuantos bytes ocupa cada entero en el archivo */
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen("numeros.bin", "rb");
        if (file == NULL) {
                printf("Archivo no se pudo abrir\n");
                return 1;
        }
        printf("-----------------------------\n");
        printf("Ingrese posicion a mostrar (0=primero)\n");
        scanf("%d", &pos);
        res = fseek(file, pos * width, SEEK_SET);
        if (res != 0) {
                printf("Error en seek");
                return 1;
        }
        fread(&val, width, 1, file);
        printf("val = 0x%x (decimal:%d)\n", val, val);
        printf("-----------------------------\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres leer un entero:

```
int entero;
fread(&entero, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

Esto copia en la dirección de entero el número de bits de un int. Para leer un Array:

```
int enteros[x];
fread(enteros, sizeof(int), x, file);
```

La función fread lo que hace es copiar en la dirección que le digas un número de elementos de un determinado tamaño leídos desde un fichero.

Así, podrías leer un fichero con 6 enteros tal que así:

```
int array[6];
FILE *in = fopen("fileName", "rb");
fread(array, sizeof(int), 6, in);
fclose(in);
```

Si el fichero no lo has creado tú con tu programa tienes que tener en cuenta el formato de los enteros almacenados (un int puede tener distinto tamaño en distintas plataformas y un 1 puede almacenarse como 0x00000001 o como 0x01000000 según sea little endian o big endian).